# How to start editing mediawiki pages?

Tags: mediawiki, tuleap

I can't find how to start mediawiki.
From my admin it is enabled, but I do not see anything that match that.
He did the command :
$> yum install php-mediawiki-tuleap-123

But after that :
"Then, as site admin, on Admin page you will find a link to Mediawiki" I can't see this link.

Answer (score 1):

As site admin, you will need to enable the plugin globally. Thereafter, as project admin, you will need to go the service configuration and enable Mediawiki, after which a link to Mediawiki will appear in the sidebar on the left.

Comment: Yes, this is what is documented. But the Mediawiki does not appear in the list of services. And my admin says that all is OK at installation time. I assume that there an installation of config issue, but I do not know how to investigate.

Comment: Here is what we found in the file system :
/usr/share/mediawiki-tuleap-123/resources/src/mediawiki
/usr/share/mediawiki-tuleap/resources/mediawiki

Comment: Here is what we found in the file system :
/usr/share/mediawiki-tuleap-123/resources/src/mediawiki
/usr/share/mediawiki-tuleap/resources/mediawiki

Installed Packages

php-mediawiki-tuleap.noarch     1.20.3-6                     "@Tuleap"

php-mediawiki-tuleap-123.noarch 1.23.9-2.el6            "@Tuleap"